# "long int", "long long" Data Types

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the purpose of these new data types? I will normally just use an "int" or a "long" but why do these exist? What new function or purpose do they bring?

Comment: They have existed for quite some time already ...

Comment: `long long int` is the same as `long long` ;)

Answer (score 5):

`long int` has always been the full name of `long`, just rarely used.

`long long` has been around for a while (in last C standard), and guarantees at least 64bit size (`long` only guarantees 32bits).

Answer (score 0):

Well, they bring a larger range of integers so computers can easily handle, for example, Bill Gates' tax returns.

As an aside, `long int` isn't very new at all but most people just use the shorter variant `long`.

Look for the sequels to these in an upcoming draft of the new ISO standards:

```
longer long      - slightly larger than a long long (this was initially put
                   forward as "long long long" but the ISO committee barfed).
even longer long - bigger yet.
stupendous long  - should keep us going for a while.
```

</humour>

Comment: Going the other way, there's an opportunity to realize a `short long`. This has the advantage of introducing no new keywords. They could also introduce a `short short` as a way of doing a guaranteed byte-length quantity, freeing up `char` to be whatever is necessary to express the local character set completely... </straight face>

Comment: c1x gives us uint8_t (or something like that) for implementations that have an 8-bit type (and the other specific bit widths). I do love the idea of a 24-bit short long for RGB values.

Comment: `echo 'long long long x;' | gcc -c -x c -`

Comment: @Donal: I actually think `short long` would be useful for something such as `int24_t`, it's a type that's often needed in embedded and low level programming - e.g. what C/C++ are good at.

Comment: @Joe: I'd have thought that would be a `long short`. ;-)

Comment: Humour aside, neither a short long nor a long short would have a _specific_ bit width, that's what the new intN\_t's are for. They'd just be between short and long bit widths. Then all you have to decide is whether a short long should be longer than a long short.

Comment: If you want a specific width, you need a numeric type that's larger and to then use the `:17` suffix (in this case, for a 17-bit type). I think; I'm a bit shaky on bitfield stuff since I don't bother to use it in my code. :-) (and @Joe: +1 for the greatest C type yet!)

Comment: @DonalFellows if `char` would be more than 8 bits, which is allowed by a standard then what would sizeof(short short) return? For 16 bit char `sizeof(short short) = 0.5`...

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously a "long long" is even longer than a "long". :)

The difference is platform-specific: "long long" can be a 64-bit integer when "long" is 32-bit or they may both be 64-bit. As for "long int", that's just the long way of saying "long", no pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

Probably to bring C++ into line with C99 which supports it (and to bring the standard into line with what compilers *actually* support, since most of them already supported long long).

Comment: Sometimes standards lag what's out there, rubber stamping common practice (and hopefully not blessing too many nasty things in the process).

Answer (score 0):

`long int` is just the full form of `long`, and is distinct from, for example `unsigned long int` and so on.  This is not new in C++0x.

`long long` is common in compilers already today; for compatibility, it is conventional that both `long` and `int` are 32 bits even on 64-bit architectures; `long long` specifies 64-bits in such circumstances; its part of C99 and must be at least 64-bits as per that standard.

You can also get 128-bit data-types on some compilers using `long long long`; other compilers provide such numbers using attributes (GCC has `__attribute__((__mode__(__TI__))))`, for example) and most have a `<limits.h>` that has an `__int128_t`/`__uint128_t`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned these types are not new. You might be interested in [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). As an additional remark, if confused about types, you could also use [intn_t types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) which have a more clearer "meaning".