# what is long long type?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“long int”, “long long” Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643487/long-int-long-long-data-types)

I am a newbie of C++ and I looked at a sample code and I saw long long type.
It says something like this

```
long long deviceId;
```

Is this same as long type? I am trying to send a device id from java(Android) to my server. In java, device id is long type(8byte) and I am putting this into the buffer like

```
bytebuffer.putLong(Long.valueOf(deviceId));
```

I am trying to parse this on my linux server using c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `long long` is longer than `long` ;)

Comment: `long long` *may* be longer than `long` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long long` is not the same as `long` (although they can have the same size, e.g. in most [64-bit POSIX system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Specific_C-language_data_models)). It is just guaranteed that a `long long` is at least as long as a `long`. In most platforms, a `long long` represents a 64-bit signed integer type.

You could use `long long` to store the 8-byte value safely in most conventional platforms, but it's better to use `int64_t`/`int_least64_t` from `<stdint.h>`/`<cstdint>` to clarify that you want an integer type having ≥64-bit.

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
int64_t deviceId;
```

Comment: I believe long-long is *at least* as big as a long, and likely larger.  But I don't believe it is guaranteed that it is longer than a long.  (I'm open to being corrected)

Comment: @abelenky: You're right. I meant `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Also it is guaranteed that `long long` is at least 64 bits.

Comment: It can't possibly be "guaranteed to be longer than long". On 64bit platforms int, long and long long are all the *same* size. At best it's "at least as long as long". There are precise minimal value range requirements on the type, though, which essentially mandate that long long be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html

> ISO C99 supports data types for
>   integers that are at least 64 bits
>   wide, and as an extension GCC supports
>   them in C90 mode and in C++. Simply
>   write long long int for a signed
>   integer, or unsigned long long int for
>   an unsigned integer. To make an
>   integer constant of type long long
>   int, add the suffix `LL' to the
>   integer. To make an integer constant
>   of type unsigned long long int, add
>   the suffix`ULL' to the integer.

Answer (score 0):

C99 and C++0x differ on the meaning of `long long int`. (There is no `long long int` in C++ 2003, although many vendors do supply it.) C99 is very specific: long long int is at least 64 bits. C++0x is incredibly vague: sizeof(long long int) >= sizeof(long int) >= sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short int) >= sizeof(signed char). The only one with special meaning is int, which is the most natural size for the execution environment.